# SQL Server permissions to execute xp_cmdshell against a network share (azure)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019, network-share

My setup:

- created "app" login
- under AppDB, create a user "app" for login "app" and granted execute, read, write
- under master db, created a user "app" for login "app", granted execute on xp_cmdshell
- on the box, created a local account "proxy" and gave it permissions to access the shared drive
- under Local Security Policy\Local Policies\User Rights Assignment\Log on as a batch job - added "proxy" local account in here
- in master db, executed `sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'box\proxy', 'pwd here'`
- restarted sql service, logged in as "app" login and tried to run `xp_cmdshell 'dir \\myshare.file.core.windows.net\myshare'`, but getting `The user name or password is incorrect.`
- ran `xp_cmdshell 'whoami'`, getting back `box\proxy` as expected

What I have tried so far:

- tried making "proxy" account an administrator on the box, restarted sql service, no luck
- tried adding "proxy" account as sql login, even giving sysadmin, again no luck
- i've changed proxy to be the same account as sql service by sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account 'box\sql_service', 'pwd here'
- when i'm running from my login, sysadmin, `xp_cmdshell 'dir \\myshare.file.core.windows.net\myshare'` everything is good
- when i'm running from "app" login, no sysadmin, getting the error `The user name or password is incorrect.`, even though, now it runs the command under same user on the box

Comment: `box\proxy` is a local account on the SQL Server machine and will be unknown to the remote share. I think you'll need an AD account rather than a local account. That being said, I suggest you avoid `xp_cmdshell` and perform file system access from via an application rather than the database engine.

Comment: totally agree with doing it from application code rather than using ```xp_cmdshell```, but at this point, that's not something I can change. ```box\proxy``` account does have access to share, I have tested it and made sure about that part. It just doesn't work when it's used as the proxy account